# Build Errors using Xamarin and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, build, installation, xamarin

I'm trying to get Visual Studio 2012 running on Windows 8 and using Xamarin.
My android sdk is installed and identified in Visual Studio 2012.  Xamarin account is verified.  I have administrator privileges on the PC.

When I try to build the generic Android Application (Hello World) that comes as a default template I get the following error:

**Access to the path 'resources.apk.bk' is denied.**

When I rebuild I get the above error plus

**The directory is not empty.**

I've search around for this a lot.  I'm going to post to stackOverflow but thought you might be able to help.

In addition I get the following warnings:
Could not find schema information for the element 'manifest'.
Could not find schema information for the element 'uses-sdk'.
Could not find schema information for the element 'application'.

Trying to build good projects from my colleagues yield similar results.

Answer (score 4):

Are you running an Anti-virus application? Most likely you are. When I first started using VS2012 I had similar issues. Our corporate developer installations separates a particular folder(s) from the anti-virus. Moving all project related files there solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the Project and click properties. Check the Compile using Android version it should be less or equal then your Android API version.